# ptor undefined in 2nd teststep

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am currently trying to get into protractor (because our automation framework is not really that awesome when it comes to angular ;)), and have now run into an interesting issue: I get the message "TypeError: Cannot call method 'waitForAngular' of undefined" in my 2nd describe block for no really apparent reason to me.

The (stripped down) code I am running can be found here, along with a stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/FrankyBoy/8675399e2236e8235e79

Any help appreciated because I am thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `beforeEach` functions only run before `it` functions, and not before `describe` functions. So the call to `ptor = protractor.getInstance()` just hasn't happened by the time you're trying to use the `ptor` object.

I suspect to fix this, you'll need to move the `waitForAngular` call into an `it` function, as follows:

```
describe('Bonus landing page', function () {
  it('should wait', function() {
    ptor.waitForAngular(); // dies with "Cannot call method 'waitForAngular' of undefined"
    // more checks were here, but it also works like this
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, thx. Big noob to both JS and Protractor ;)  

Reason I was asking: I was doing some (sub)page-object which took an element and then was doing some find-children-stuff in the constructor which failed (my guess: because synchronous vs promises) and when I tore down the code to a more manageable size I ended up with the gist I posted.  

OT Question: that behaviour happened also if the code was in the 2nd describe-block - as I don't unassign the ptor anywhere how come its ndef again and not still assigned to the value from the first block?